# Erro na Criação de Banco POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tendo o seguinte erro na hora da criação de um banco de dados POSTGRESQL:

[image: SS]

[image: SS]

CÓDIGO SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE pesadaum;

CREATE TABLE user(
    user_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    heavy_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE admin_user(
    admin_user_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    heavy_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    admin_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    rg varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    cpf varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    access_lvl boolean NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE problem(
    problem_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address point,
    description text
    user_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES user(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE img(
    img_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status_acc boolean,
    problem_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES problem_id(problem_id)
);

CREATE TABLE error(
    error_id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    error_name varchar(255),
    error_description TEXT,
);

CREATE TABLE error_problem_plug(
    problem_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES problem(problem_id),
    error_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES error(error_id)
);
```

Comment: Apenas um detalhe não mencionado explicitamente: USER é uma palavra chave reservada tanto no PostgreSQL quanto nas especificações SQL:2016, SQL:2011 e SQL-92. A maneira de contornar isto é a utilização de "Quoted identifiers", por exemplo: "user" mas neste caso sempre terá que utilizar as aspas quando referenciar este campo. Note que para Quoted identifiers "user", "USER" e "User" são identificadores distintos, o que não acontece com identificadores comuns: foo, FOO ou Foo se referem ao mesmo identificador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue seu scritp convertido, mas num fique mal acostumado não :D

```
CREATE DATABASE pesadaum;

CREATE TABLE "user"(
    user_id  serial NOT NULL ,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    heavy_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE admin_user(
    admin_user_id serial  NOT NULL ,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    heavy_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    admin_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    rg varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    cpf varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    access_lvl boolean NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(admin_user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE problem(
    problem_id serial NOT NULL ,
    address point,
    description text,
    user_id int ,
    PRIMARY KEY(problem_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user" (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE img(
    img_id serial NOT NULL ,
    url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status_acc boolean,
    problem_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES "problem"(problem_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(img_id)
);

CREATE TABLE error(
    error_id serial NOT NULL ,
    error_name varchar(255),
    error_description TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (error_id)
);

CREATE TABLE error_problem_plug(
    problem_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES "problem"(problem_id),
    error_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES "error"(error_id)
);
```

Comment: haha mto obrigado! Realmente tava apanhando. Já até comprei um livro de PostgreSQL :D

Answer (score 3):

Essa sintaxe não é do PostgreSQL, é do SQL de outro banco de dados.

Começa pelo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. O correto seria o uso de `SERIAL`.

Tem erro que não identifiquei, pode ter ocorrido em consequência desses. Precisa aprender interpretar os erros por conta própria, vários acontecerão.

Answer (score 1):

O Script com erro parece do MySQL.

O primeiro erro é syntax error at or near "user" isso ocorre por que existe um objeto chamado user no portgres.

Se você executar a consulta "select user" ela retornará o usuário conectado.

Quando você define um atributo da tabela como serial uma sequence é criada e o valor default do atributo passa a ser o nextval()

o Script da tabela usuário ficaria assim:

```
  CREATE TABLE "user"(
user_id  serial NOT NULL ,
email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
heavy_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
```